# How to Redirect ot my asp.net intranet website from current JSP(java) Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, redirect, tomcat5.5

I wants to redirect to my asp.net intranet website from current JSP (java) site 
by putting a url in my current in java site hosted under tomcat

Any suggestion really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a line as follows on the page you want the redirection to happen. (Maybe index.jsp?)

```
<%
response.sendRedirect( "http://url.of.the.asp.page" ) ;
%>
```